# How to return javascript results to jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem returning results from javascript to json. I am an armature at programming, so please forgive my lack of understanding. Ok...I will try my best to explain what I am doing atm.

1. I have a jquery function that passes a "farmid" variable on the event "OnClick" to an "asp" script. Here is the function..

   ```
   scriptUrl = "urlpath/weatherrainfall.asp?farmid="+farmid;
   $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        url: scriptUrl,
        dataType: "text",
        async: false,
        success: function(returnval){
            document.getElementById('obs').innerHTML = returnval;
   });
   ```
2. The asp script then runs a postgis "ST_Distance" query to find the closest weather station to the farm.
3. The closest weather "station id" is then passed on to jquery getJSON.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('bomproxy.asp?url=http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDV60801/IDV60801.'+wmo+'.json',
              function(json) {
   ```
4. The json results are then passed to "highcharts api" to draw the chart for that weather station.

THE PROBLEM: The chart does not show the chart in the 'obs' div as expected in step 1, it only shows return the "loading" html not he hightchart javascript. But if I load the "asp" page... weatherrainfall.asp?farmid="+farmid script on its own...I works fine!. What am I doing wrong in the jquery? How could I do this better?

Comment: Post a more complete section of your code so we can see what it's doing rather than have you try and abstractly describe the flow. If the page gets stuck on 'loading', I'm guessing there's a JS error causing the interpreter to break. Open your browser's JavaScript console, and paste the full error message here as well. For one thing you're missing the closing parentheses and braces for your 'success' callback. Either way, it is extremely unclear what you are having trouble 'passing'. jQuery is simply a JS library, they are not two different entities that you pass things between.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$.getJSON is for a json object, if your asp page is returning a chart when you go to it on its own, then you should be using $.ajax instead.

And on a unrelated personal note, you should learn asp.net, the mere fact that people still use asp makes me die inside.

Comment: Yes I agree ASP classic is bad.... but its all I know atm. And I have very short timelines to deliver a working example. Yes I plan on evolving to asp.net. Thanks for the suggestion on $.ajax I am trying to change the $getjson function to $.ajax atm. I might need further help by the look of it. Is the $.ajax you ae talking about. 
    $.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    context: document.body
    }).done(function() {
    $(this).addClass("done");
    });